# Light through the wall in a custom model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I create a model of a room on blender.
Then I position some spot lights in my scene, but they pass over the wall.
The wall is modelled with a normal plane.
What can be the cause of this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15708/light-through-the-wall-in-a-custom-model/) by [jony](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3140/jony/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imstevenpm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3874/imstevenpm/) on 2017-12-11**:
Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, this is currently a limitation of spotlights in Gazebo. There is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2083/point-and-spot-lights-dont-cast-shadows) ticketed for this, you could vote for it so it starts getting more attention.

Meanwhile, you could try using directional lights, if possible.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jony](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3140/jony/) on 2017-03-29**:
thank you so much